# PowerPoint vb.net reference current slide

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto, powerpoint

Writing an addin for PowerPoint in VB .NET and any line I've written to insert various shape types, I get the error:
"Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

I've Googled it and all the suggestions begin with

```
Slide.Shapes.AddShape
```

Though that gives the error above, e.g.

```
NewBubble = Slide.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeOval, 20, 150 + (i * 10), cm2points(0.4), cm2points(0.4))
```

So, how do I reference the active slide so that I can then go ".Shapes" or whatever else?

I've got "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint" up the top and have tried "PowerPoint. etc" and "Application. etc" but doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using: `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide`?

How about: `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide`?

I think you can also handle `Application.SlideSelectionChanged` and then get to the selected slides as a `SlideRange` to the event handler parameter.

Comment: Gorgeous mate - first line works. Thank you! I tried variations of but didn't get all the bits :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm speaking VBA and not VB.NET here, but translation shouldn't be too difficult:

In normal (ie, editing) view, this will give you a reference to the current slide:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)
```

If you're in slide show view, you use this to get a reference to the current slide:

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide
```

with the caveat that there can be more than one slide show window if more than one slide show is in progress (rare, but it can happen). To be safe, check SlideShowWindows.Count first.

Comment: That's where I started - the VBA is much more straightforward but doesn't translate that easily... (I can't seem to find the equivalent of 'ActiveWindow', among other attempted solutions)